# Can not connect to AWS dynamodb with laravel with kitar / laravel-dynamodb

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, laravel-10

When I try to connect with dynamodb using kitar / laravel-dynamodb it will always return " Call to a member function prepare() on null" back to me. What should I do? And how to fix that?